# Running a python (with MySQL) script from PHP

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm trying to use a PHP site button to kick off a python script on my server.  When I run it, everything seems fine, on the server I can "ps ax" and see that the script is running.

The Python script attempts to process some files and write the results to a MySQL database.  When I ultimately check to see that the changes were made to the DB, nothing has happened.  Also, redirecting output shows no errors.

I have checked to make sure that it's executing (the ps ax)
I've made sure that all users have access to writing to the output directory (for saving the error report, if there is one)
I've made sure that the logon to MySql is correct...

I'm not sure what else to do or check.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your web-server logs.(/var/www/log/apache2/error.log) if you have apache as your webserver..